# Does a line have 2 degrees of freedom or 1 degree of freedom?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, plane-geometry

We know that dimensions depend on degree of freedom. For example any line $ax+by+c=0$ in 2D plane is 1 dimensional because if I know the $x$ or $y$ value, we calculate the $y$ or $x$ value. That's why the line has dimension $1$. But [many places](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/degrees-of-freedom-for-lines.276263/) are saying that line is $2$ dimensional, I am very confused by this, what is right?

Comment: What places are saying line is $2$ dimensional? This question cannot be answered without context.

Comment: @Ninad see the above hyperlink.

Comment: That is not a feature of lines. That is because the lines live in $\Bbb{R}^2$ so their *placement* in a $2$D world has two degrees of freedom. This has little to do with the structure of the line itself.

Comment: Consider [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198663/how-many-degrees-of-freedom-does-a-line-have-on-a-plane) link

Comment: @Om3ga could explain in Hagen answer Why this is not relevant?---"their position on the line is irrelevant" .. Why we substruct 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confused because these are different things.

1. To pick a point from the set of points on  a given line: one degree of freedom (by the argument you give)
2. To pick a line from the set of lines in a plane: two degrees of freedom (e.g., its direction and its distance from the origin; or: pick two points in the plane = 4 degrees, but subtract 2 degrees because their position on the line is irrelevant; or ...)
3. To pick a line from the set of lines in 3d space: four degrees of freedom (why?)

Comment: could explain why this is not relevant?---"their position on the line is irrelevant"