# How degree of freedom of lines in 3D space is 4?

Tags: geometry, 3d, plane-geometry

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317527/does-a-line-have-2-degrees-of-freedom-or-1-degree-of-freedom/4317535#4317535) that degree of freedom of lines in 2D plane is 2.

Proof:- Suppose take two points $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2).$ So therefore degree of freedom is 4.But subtract 2 because their position on the line is irrelevant.

My question is what does mean of "subtract 2 because their position on the line is irrelevant "?

And I also read from that question degree of freedom of line in 3D space is 4.

My approach is, we take two arbitrary points to draw line in 3D.It has 6 degrees of freedom.

But why we subtract 2 from 6? Don't understand.

N. B. - I want to understand intuition rather than complex mathematics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 2D, you can define a line by an angle $\theta$ and a (signed) distance $d$. The equation of the line is $x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta = d$. The line is normal to the vector $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ and it’s at a distance $d$ from the origin. So a 2D line has two degrees of freedom (as specified by $\theta$ and $d$).

Note that this is an **infinite** line. You seem to be thinking about a bounded line segment defined by its two end-points. A bounded line segment in 2D does indeed have 4 degrees of freedom.

Suppose you use two points to define an infinite 2D line. So, you’re using four numbers, and maybe this makes you think that the line has 4 degrees of freedom. But you can slide each of the two points along the line, and you’ll still get the same line. The sliding motions of the two points correspond to two degrees of freedom that are doing nothing to help with the definition of the line. So, two degrees of freedom are wasted, and the line really only has two degrees of freedom, not 4.

In 3D, it’s true that an (unbounded) line has 4 degrees of freedom, but finding a line representation that uses only 4 numbers is fairly complicated. One easy but incomplete solution is to use the intersection of the line with two planes, say the $xy$ plane and the $xz$ plane. That gives you a representation using 4 numbers, but it doesn’t work for all lines.

Again, a **bounded** 3D line segment does have 6 degrees of freedom.

Comment: could you explain little bit "The sliding motions of the two points correspond to two degrees of freedom"-- how sliding motion of 2 point correspondence to 2 dof?

Comment: @Stack I think they mean, motion along the line has one degree of freedom. So two points retain two degrees of freedom.

Comment: @MyMolecules why motion along the line is 1 degree, I can move both direction, so it should 2 degree of freedom?

Comment: @MyMolecules could you explain why motion has one degree of freedom?

Comment: A point can move distance of $r$ along the line. This $r$ is the single degree of freedom. Its value can be positive, negative or zero, so it covers both directions you mention. (Recall the real number line.)

Comment: @MyMolecules but why we subtract 2 from 4,if a point in the line, we should subtract 1?

Comment: @Stack 1 point has 1 dof; so 2 points will have 2 dof.

Comment: For each point ... you need to remove one degree of freedom because it's constrained to lie on the line. This leaves one degree of freedom. So, remove one degree of freedom for each point, which means you're removing a total of two.

Comment: If it confuses you, forget about "removing" degrees of freedom. An infinite line can be described by two numbers (like the $d$ and $\theta$ in my answer). So, it has two degrees of freedom. That's it -- end of story.

Comment: [+1] See my answer mentionning (redundant system of) Plücker coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

To specify a line in $3D$ you need a direction vector and a point $(a,b,c)$.  Direction vectors can be assumed to be unit vectors and thus can be specified by two parameters (when parameterized using spherical coordinates).  Point $(a,b,c)$ is any point on the line, and can be specified by two coordinates on the plane passing through the origin and normal to the direction vector.  Hence, the total number of parameters needed to uniquely determine a line is $4$.

Comment: This is not quite correct because your line is not oriented and thus corresponds to **two** points on the unit  sphere

Comment: @Georges could you explain in bubba' answer little bit "The sliding motions of the two points correspond to two degrees of freedom"-- how sliding motion of 2 point correspondence to 2 dof?

Comment: @Georges, can be post a solution so I know where I went wrong ?

Comment: I am sorry I don't follow your argument.

Comment: @potato could you explain in bubba' answer little bit "The sliding motions of the two points correspond to two degrees of freedom"-- how sliding motion of 2 point correspondence to 2 dof?

Comment: @stack I think you should direct this question to bubba himself.

Comment: @Potato bubba isn't replying...

Comment: @Potato Suppose your line is $x=y=0$: there is no single direction vector associated to it. Indeed you could choose $(0,0,1)$ or $(0,0,-1)$ and there is no way you can make a compatible  choice for all lines. You have to parametrize directions by the projective plane $\mathbb P^2_\mathbb R$, which is the quotient topological space of the sphere $S^2$ by the antipodal relation $(x,y,z)\cong (-x,-y,-z)$.

Comment: So what's the answer then ?

Comment: The answer is that the set of lines in $\mathbb R^3$ is a big open subset of the Grassmannian manifold $\operatorname {Gr}(2,\mathbb R^4)=\operatorname {Gr}(1,\mathbb P^3)$. That manifold is of dimension $4$, just as in your answer, but is not an open subset of $\mathbb R^4$, and thus  not so easy to describe in an elementary way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen mentionned that the set of lines in $\mathbb{R^3}$ can very efficiently be parametrized by **Plücker coordinates**.

This sytem of *redundant* coordinates associate to a line:

- a directing vector $\vec{V}$ and
- the "torque" vector $\vec{T}=\vec{OM} \times \vec{V}$ where $M$ is any point on the line.

In this way, a line is described by $3 + 3$ coordinates, but this does not mean 6 dof (degrees of freedom).

We must first subtract one dof because  $\vec{V}$ is defined up to a multiplication by a scalar, and another one because

$$\vec{T} \perp \vec{V} \ \iff \ \vec{T}\cdot\vec{V}=0 $$ giving another relationship between the six coordinates.

In this way we remain with 4 dof.

This set of lines constitute a so-called grassmannian manifold (generalized surface), more precisely the [Klein Quadric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_quadric).

Remarks:

For applications of Plücker coordinates, see this [PhD thesis](http://www.unilim.fr/pages_perso/oana.apostu/fichiers/TheseOanaLiviaAPOSTU.pdf).

An interesting application of the Klein quadric can be found in this recent [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329772112_A_finite_geometric_toy_model_of_space-time_as_an_error_correcting_code/figures?lo=1).

Comment: Any comment ?...